# How to sort list by name?

Tags: angular

I'm using angular reactive forms and want to sort data in drop down list in alphabetical order.

This is My code:

```
<md-select placeholder="Select Cost Center" required formControlName="costCenterId" [(ngModel)]="selectedCostCenter">
        <md-option *ngFor="let costCenter of costCenters" [value]="costCenter.costCenterId">
          {{ costCenter.costCenterName }}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
```

Comment: You should sort your array before using it in html.

Comment: you can use the array.sort() method

Comment: you can use a pipe to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sort the cost centers in your code.

```
this.costCenters.sort((a, b) => a.costCenterName.localCompare(b.costCenterName));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use material autocomplete](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-autocomplete-configuration)

HTML:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Filter Name" aria-label="Assignee" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface User {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    { name: 'Mary' },
    { name: 'Masy' },
    { name: 'Maty' },
    { name: 'Mvry' },
    { name: 'Mbry' },
    { name: 'Shelley' },
    { name: 'Igor' }
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
      startWith<string | User>(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
      map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:
you don't need to change TS file only copy this code and paste it.

```
    <md-select placeholder="Select Cost Center" required formControlName="costCenterId" [(ngModel)]="selectedCostCenter">
        <md-option ng-value="costCenter.costCenterId" ng-repeat="costCenter in costCenters | orderBy:costCenterName">{{ costCenter.costCenterName }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
```